# Reading a file by word without using split in Python

Tags: python

I have a one line file that I want to read word by word, i.e., with space separating words. Is there a way to do this without loading the data into the memory and using split? The file is too large.

Comment: Could you read character-by-character and keep track of when there's a space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file char by char and yield a word after each new white space, below is a simple solution for a file with single white spaces, you should refine it for complex cases (tabs, multiple spaces, etc).

```
def read_words(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        out = ''
        while True:
            c = f.read(1)
            if not c:
                break
            elif c == ' ':
                yield out
                out = ''
            else:
                out += c
```

Example:

```
for i in read_words("test"):
    print i
```

It uses a generator to avoid have to allocate a big chunk of memory

Comment: But what if the file is one tremendously long line?

Comment: `without using split in Python`

Answer (score 0):

Try this little function:

```
def readword(file):
c = ''
word = ''
while c != ' ' and c != '\n':
    word += c
    c = file.read(1)
return word
```

Then to use it, you can do something like:

```
f = open('file.ext', 'r')
print(readword(f))
```

This will read the first word in the file, so if your file is like this:

```
12 22 word x yy
another word
...
```

then the output should be `12`.

Next time you call this function, it will read the next word, and so on...